# Passing a variable into a cfcomponent initialization method

Tags: coldfusion-10

If I'm doing the following :

```
<cfobject name="EmployeePermissions" component="CFCs.Permissions"  > 

<cfoutput> 
    Username: #EmployeePermissions.UserName#<br> 
</cfoutput>
```

Using component:

```
<cfcomponent> 

    <cfset This.UserName = '' > 

    <cffunction name="init" access="public" output="no" returntype="Permissions"> 
        <cfargument name="UserName" type="string" required="yes"> 

        <cfset variables.UserName = arguments.UserName > 

        <cfreturn this> 
    </cffunction> 

</cfcomponent>
```

The initialization method doesn't seem to be called. Further, the object can be used without ever specifying a username. How do I require the username and ensure the init method is called?

Answer (score 0):

Hope, the below answer will clear your doubts.

```
<cfobject name="EmployeePermissions" component="CFCs.Permissions"  >
<cfset getUser = EmployeePermissions.init(UserName = "jawa")>
<cfoutput>
    #getUser#
</cfoutput>
```